# regex to search 8 character string for two consecutive numbers and letters afterwards

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I am new to regular expressions and I find myself stuck on this problem.

I have an 8 character string that has been previously filtered to be only an alpha numeric so this string will only contain numbers and letters.  What I am looking to do is find the first two consecutive digits anywhere within the string and once that is found make sure that any characters after the two consecutive digits are all alpha characters a-z if it doesn't match this it just return false;
so far I have

`var str = "abc11hsb`";

```
var testIt = /[0-9]{2}/i;
var test = testIt.test(str);
test //true
```

However if I have this string

```
var str = "abc11h7b";
```

and I run the same test as above it should return false because after the first two digit match every character afterwards should be an alpha character a-z.  the above string has a 7 after the 11; my regex only accounts for finding two consecutive numbers but doesn't account for the fact that each character after those first two digits should be an alpha character essentially a-z.

Hope this is clear

Again your help is always greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression: `/[0-9]{2}[a-z]+$/i`

Comment: hey jay - thanks for the answer much appreciated, I will accept soon as the right answer - could I expand on that regex to include an exception that the two digits could be the last characters in the string as well - again thanks

Comment: sure, you can replace + with * as follows /[0-9]{2}[a-z]*$/i